# Semantic UI not validating dynamically generated dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a dynamically added Semantic UI dropdown with the name "language2" and the validation rule:

```
language2: {
  identifier: 'language2',
  rules: [
    {
      type: 'empty',
      prompt: 'Please select a language',
    }
  ]
},
```

Here I call the function that dynamically adds the dropdown:
`document.getElementById('addDivButton').addEventListener('click', addDiv)`;

The dropdown is initialised inside the `addDiv` function.
However, the menu is not being validated.
All other hardcoded elements in the form validate fine. Only this dynamically generated one.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what to do. You need to include a copy of the rule inside the function addDiv in order to validate dynamic elements.